# What are the ECLIPSEF.RSA and ECLIPSEF.SF in a java jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I have a Maven project which I'm developing in IntelliJ. When I build a .jar file from this project (an artifact which I need to debug my Spark jobs) there are these two files in the .jar file:

```
 /META-INF/ECLIPSEF.SF
 /META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
```

What are these files and why they end up in my jar file? I am asking because they are preventing my Spark jobs from running.

Comment: [Found this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371954).

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the maven shade plugin? Those are jar signatures, which ensure that the jar has not been tampered with. If you're using the maven-shade-plugin, you need to strip them out because you are intentionally changing the jar:

```
<filter>
    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
    </excludes>
</filter>
```

Comment: I am new to Java and to be honest do not know what this maven shade plugin does and whether IntelliJ uses it behind the scenes. Otherwise I have not installed any plugin in IntelliJ whatsoever

Comment: Does the word `maven-shade-plugin` appear in your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: No it does not. But could it be that IntelliJ is using it behind the scenes to generate the jar.

Comment: If IntelliJ is building the jar for you instead of maven, then you'll need to modify the artifact definition to exclude the 3 types of files in my answer above.

Comment: Yes but where is the artifact definition in IntelliJ. There is indeed an .iml file in the .idea/artifacts folder but its xml schema does not seem to be able to accommodate your <filter></filter> element.

Comment: @MilenKovachev No, the XML is for the maven-shade-plugin, not IntelliJ (You tagged this question with `maven`, I assumed you're building your artifacts with Maven and not with IntelliJ). I'm not familiar enough with IntelliJ's artifact configuration to provide precise instructions for that :(